# Put component next to User Control

Tags: asp.net, .net, html-table, user-controls

I have a table in which I put a User Control in one row. I would like to put something to its right (like divide the td in two)

```
 <table id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
   <tr valign="top">
     <td>
    <div>
     <uc3:Quicksportselection ID="QuickSportSelection1" runat="server"></uc3:Quicksportselection>
     </div>
     <div class="sBody">
       <hr />
        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="SponsorListRad" RepeatDirection="Vertical"  RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="labels">
           <asp:ListItem Text="Eurosport" Value="Eurosport"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="Discovery" Value="Discovery"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
      </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Doing such thing will put my 'SponsorListRad' UNDER the UserControl. How can I put it next to it on the right?

Answer (score 0):

The `<hr>` tag defines a thematic break in an HTML page and it's used to separate content and in this case - should be delete.

Comment: What's in the `sBody` class? Isn't there something like line separator?

Comment: No it is fine I'll stop here. thanks for your answer